# Image Reconstruction:Phase vs. Magnitude

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, frequency, signal-processing, image-processing

Figure 1.(c) shows the Test image reconstructed from MAGNITUDE spectrum only. We can say that the intensity values of LOW frequency pixels are comparatively more than HIGH frequency pixels.

$$
f(x,y)= ∑_(u=0)^(U-1)∑(v=0)^(V-1)\ |F(u,v)| exp^(1j*2Π*xu)/M) * e^(1j*2Π*(vy)/N) / 
$$

Figure 1.(d) shows the Test image reconstructed from PHASE spectrum only. We can say that intensity values of HIGH frequency (edges,lines) pixels are comparatively more than LOW frequency pixels.

Why this magical contradiction of intensity change (or exchange) is present between Test image reconstructed from MAGNITUDE spectrum only and Test image reconstructed from PHASE spectrum only, which when combined together form the original Test image?

$$
f(x,y)= ∑_(u=0)^(U-1)∑(v=0)^(V-1)\ exp(j*angle(u,v)) *exp^(1j*2Π*xu)/M) * e^(1j*2Π*(vy)/N)  
$$

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would probably be best to take the extra image out (or somehow work it in, perhaps as a different answer?). It was fascinating to see though, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## Spectral Power – Image B (top right).

The nature of images C and D is explained by the spectral power image, B.

You can see from spectral power image that most energy is concentrated at low frequencies (the brighter middle part of the image). The higher frequencies (moving away from the centre) have less energy in them because there is less brightness in this part of the image.

This kind of power spectrum is [typical in natural images](http://www-ist.massey.ac.nz/dbailey/sprg/IVCNZ/Proceedings/IVCNZ_27.pdf). The drop off in energy with frequency tends to be a good fit to an exponential function.

## Energy Image – C (bottom left)

Given this, image C (bottom left) makes sense. You would expect to see blobby shapes that are prevalently low frequency, because that's where the power is in the image. It's symmetry is due to the phases being all all set to zero.

## Phase Image – D (bottom right)

You have provided the function used to reconstruct the phase only function. If you take out the summations and basis functions, you are left with:

```
F_phase_only(u,v) = F(u,v) / |F(u,v)|
```

F(u,v) is a complex number with phase and magnitude. You are dividing by the magnitude to eliminate it – to make it be 1 for all components. So, F_phase_only(u,v) just has the phases. The magnitude of F_phase_only(u,v) = 1, for all u,v.

Now, look at the spectral image again (top right). This is really just a plot of |F(u,v)| – it's a magnitude only image.

- We can see that for small u,v, **the low frequencies** that are at the middle of the image, |F(u,v)| is large, because the middle is bright.
- For larger u,v **the higher frequencies** that are away from the middle, |F(u,v)| is relatively small, because these parts of the image are darker.

So, returning to F_phase_only(u,v), I will re-write it very subtly.

```
F_phase_only(u,v) = F(u,v) . BOOST(u,v).
```

What is boost?

```
BOOST(u,v) = 1 / |F(u,v)|
```

What can we determine about the nature of BOOST?

- For small u,v **the low frequencies**, BOOST(u,v) *must* be a small number. It must be small, because BOOST is the reciprocal of the magnitude. We know from the spectrum that the **magnitude is large for low** frequencies. Thus, BOOST(u,v) must be small and thus **diminishes low frequencies**.
- For larger u,v **the high frequencies**, BOOST(u,v) *must* be a large number. It must be large, because BOOST is the reciprocal of the magnitude. We know from the spectrum that the magnitude is **small for high frequencies**. Thus, BOOST(u,v) must be large and thus **enhances high frequencies**.

So the "phase only" image gives all frequency domain components the same magnitude. For an individual component taken relative to the others, **this enormously emphasises a higher frequency components and greatly diminishes low frequency components**.

So, while you have called it a "phase only image", really it's an image where high frequency terms are enormously enhanced at the expense of low frequency terms.

For this reason, the resulting image shows the edge like features that exist in the magnified higher frequencies.

## A Fairer Phase image

Given the [paper I mentioned previously](http://www-ist.massey.ac.nz/dbailey/sprg/IVCNZ/Proceedings/IVCNZ_27.pdf), you could prepare a fairer phase image.

```
F_fairer_phase(u,v) = Expected(u,v) . F(u,v) / |F(u,v)|
```

Where `Expected(u,v)` is the statistically expected spectral power at u,v – left as an exercise :-)

Alternatively you could derive `Expected(u,v)` by averaging over all `|F(w,x)|` where `sqrt(w.w + x.x) = sqrt(u.u, v.v)`.

Comment: sir, i have added equations for the reconstruction of image from magnitude only and phase only. i want to ask in last paragraph that in phase only reconstruction part why do i get only edges or  lines,**why not low frequency components??** **because from the 2nd equation i am not getting any idea that only edge like features are emphasized**... thank u

Comment: thank u very much sir for your feedback.can u suggest any article or video or any link for phase only reconstruction ?? Thank u once again

Comment: sir i read your answer but i have doubt about "BOOST". In my 2nd equation of my question,if i convert F(u,v) into polar form i.e.F(u,v)=|F(u,v)|×exp(1j*angle(u,v)) and put it into the equation, the |F(u,v)| term will get cancelled. So i think that boost factor is also cancelled and only exponential term is remains at the right side of the equation.

Comment: That's precisely correct. The magnitude is "canceled" (becomes 1) because you divide by the magnitude. But before (in the original image) magnitude _wasn't_ canceled. So, compared to the original, the magnitude for high frequencies is greater and for low frequencies is less. Thus edges are enhanced.

Comment: sorry sir,but i am not getting what u want to say...

Comment: but how? i think only exponential part is remaining and no magnitude part in equation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15383/discussion-between-benjohn-and-sagar).

Comment: sir, i have uploaded image of magnitude &phase exchange in the question.thanks for helping..

Comment: :-) That's a really interesting effect, thank you for passing it on. The next question is: why is our perception of images based almost entirely on phase information rather than magnitude. I don't have an answer to that. All the best!